# Team matchmaking based on ELO score

Tags: algorithm, matchmaking, competition

I'm looking for a very simple way to put up 2 teams out of unspecified amount of players. So its not actually a standard matchmaking since it only creates one match out of the whole pool of queued players.
I do have pretty much only single variable and it is the ELO score for each player, which means it's the only available option to base calculations on.

What I thought of is just simply go through every possible combination of a players(4 in each team) and the lowest difference between the average ELO of teams is the final rosters that get created. But it would be the most unoptimized way to do that.

So I decided to ask a question in here, maybe you can help me with that in some way.

Comment: This appears to be a variant of the knapsack problem for which several algorithms exist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem